# Unable to load WSDL File/Location in Delphi for VIES SOAP Service

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-xe2

I am trying to create a Delphi XE2 function to check VAT numbers via the SOAP service of VIES: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

When I use Delphi X2's  WSDL importer with the above URL taking the default values, I get the following error:
Unable to load WSDL File/Location: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl.  Error [The requested header was not found - URL:http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl - SOAPAction:""

What am I doing worng?

Comment: I am using Dr Bob's tutorial for soap http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinE2.htm where he uses the checkVatService.wsdl and stumbled upon the same problem @Pep describes when using XE3. (However, the WSDL import works for XE)

Comment: You can import the WSDL using another version of Delphi, if possible. The generated import unit will work with later editions (I'm using it with XE8 today, without any further changes)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save the wsdl file to disc and import the saved xml file.
After generating the pas file, change the line matchCode = (1, 2) in (_1, _2).

Comment: Thank you, saving it to disk avoided the issue.  However, it was not necessary to change (1, 2) to (_1, _2) because it was already generated with (_1, _2)

Comment: Thank you @Arjen van der Spek this solved the problem for XE3 as well!

Comment: This solve the issue in Delphi 10 too. Thanks. No need to rename (1,2) in (_1, _2). The generated code now is "matchCode = (_1, _2, _3);"

Comment: Solved the same problem in 10.4 Sydney, no need to change anything