# importing a wsdl file in delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, wsdl, delphi-xe3

I have to address a webservice with SOAP.

the WSDL file is http://www.healthconnect.be/sites/default/files/support/ConsultMyCareNet.wsdl

However when I import this WSDL file in my project (Delphi XE3) with file- new - other - WSDL importer there are some faults,

In top of the new *.pas file I find:

> The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
>   in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
>   to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
>   typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also
>   indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.*

```
// !:GetMCNStatusRequest - "urn:be:healthconnect:rrnconnector:ws:1_0:messages"
// !:GetMCNStatusResponse - "urn:be:healthconnect:rrnconnector:ws:1_0:messages"**
```

and thus the following important and necessary function for addressing the webservice cannot be compiled
with the message:

```
Cannot unwrap:
 - Input part does not refer to an element
 - Output part does not refer to an element*
```

```
function getMCNStatus(const parameters: GetMCNStatusRequest): GetMCNStatusResponse; stdcall;
```

But I need this function 'getMCNStatus' as It is a the first function to call since this function tests if the connection with the webservice is Ok. Without this function the rest does not work.

So how can I make this function work anyway?

Must I define the classes `GetMCNStatusRequest` and `GetMCNStatusResponse` myself and what Do I have to define in the classes ? Can I find the answer in the wsdl file ?

Answer (score 0):

open your wsdl file.
Remove following lines within types tag.

```
   <xs:import namespace="urn:be:healthconnect:rrnconnector:ws:1_0:person"     schemaLocation="person-1-0.xsd" /> 
   <xs:import namespace="urn:be:healthconnect:rrnconnector:ws:1_0:common" schemaLocation="common-1-0.xsd" /> 
   <xs:import namespace="urn:be:healthconnect:rrnconnector:ws:1_0:messages" schemaLocation="messages-1-0.xsd" />
```

Now , you won't get any error while importing wsdl.
Update: Reason

Why is it happening?
Instead of defining element types in your wsdl file, you are importing these namespaces which has defined xsd files like person-1-0.xsd or common-1-0.xsd Which is not accessible. These namesapaces should be like

```
"http://healthconnect/example"
```

Comment: That does not work on the contrary there are more faults I tried to add the classes getmcnstatusrequest en getmcnstatusresponse in the wsdl file based on information in the xsd files, then the compilation is ok but there is an application error when calling getmcnstatusrequest

Comment: There were cases when WSDL importer from some strange reason did not work with URL, but did work with local file like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177991/unable-to-load-wsdl-file-location-in-delphi-for-vies-soap-service). So I'd try to download all related files (incl. *.xsd) and import them from a local disk.

Comment: when i save the wsdl file to the local disk and import this file none of the definitions of the xsd files are imported in the wsdl file, even if I change the import path in the wsdl file to the local disk where the files are located

Comment: Have you placed those xsds with same name as in wsdl and in same directory where wsdl is located? You don't have to change anything in wsdl then.

Comment: yes I just did, but the definitions of the xsd's are not imported at all; when I import from the website then everthing but 4 definitions are imported, and one of them that is not imported is crucial for the request

Comment: i am out of options now. You can try including those element definitions from xsd to wsdl definition under types tag under. But you have to change references for message types with tns instead of messages.

Comment: It finally worked after saving the wsdl and xsd files locally to disk, doing some minor modifications in the xsd files and using the commandline wdslimp

Comment: good,you can include your findings as answer, may be some day it will help someone. cheers!